# Permission to request prediction from Cloud Function denied

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I deployed a model (TensorFlow) on Google Cloud AI Platform and I am trying to get prediction from Cloud Function after deploying a node.js via Firebase account. And the error says:

`Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details: Permission denied on resource project skinskanproject-capstone.`

And here is the details from logs:

```
Error: Permission denied on resource project skinskanproject-capstone. at Gaxios._request (/workspace/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:127:23) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) at async Compute.requestAsync (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:343:18) at async /workspace/lib/index.js:26:19
```

Here is the node.js code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import { google } from 'googleapis';
const ml = google.ml('v1')

export const predictCancer = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    
    const instances = request.body.instances;
    const model = request.body.model;

    const { credential } = await google.auth.getApplicationDefault();
    const modelName = `projects/skinskanproject-capstone/models/${model}`;

    const preds = await ml.projects.predict({
        auth: credential,
        name: modelName,
        requestBody: { 
            instances
        }
    } as any);

    response.send(JSON.stringify(preds.data))

});
```

Is there any IAM settings or authentication step I am missing?

Comment: You need to authorize your function to call your model, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/access-control#model_roles). The role ml.modelUser seams the right one.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for the answer, and do you know where should I put or configure this role for my function?

Comment: By default, Google Cloud Functions use App Engine Default Service account as identity. So, grant the permission on the service account email `<PROJECT_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. And try again. Let me know if it works.

Comment: As @guillaumeblaquiere mentioned, you need to authorise Cloud Functions to call your model for predictions. In addition, this is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account) where it explains about the Cloud Functions Service account.